# JQuery: When appending information to a modal, how can I expand it to include the new div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, modal-dialog

How can I make it so that when the new DIV is appended, the modal gets expanded?

I'm opening a modal window to edit some information with ajax. After submitting the information, I'm appending an Alert div to the modal window, but scrollbars are added to the modal because there was not enough room for the new div. Please keep in mind that I'm appending information from inside the modal itself!

Thanks a lot!!

edit: I'm using jQuery UI for the modal.

edit: this is how I open my modal:

```
    $( "#btn_new" ).live('click',function() {
        var iframe = $('<iframe src="users_new.php" />');

        iframe.dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            title: "Nuevo Usuario",
            width: 370,
            height: 520,
            show: "fade",
            hide: "fade",
            modal: true,
            resizable: true,
            buttons: {
                "Cerrar": function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
            }).width(370 - 12).height(520 - 15);
        });
```

Comment: Did you try overriding the overflow from css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which modal frame work did you use? jquery UI? Lightbox? They are using fixed size so I think you have to modify the size yourself. After append the div you can add div height / width to the modal dialog.
Just example:

```
var div = $('<div/>');
$('#modal').append(div);
//Jquery ui
$("#modal").dialog( "option", "height", oldheight + div.height());
```

Comment: but how can i call $("#modal").dialog from inside the modal itself?? I'm using Jquery ui, sorry. I'll update my question... thanks!

Comment: Just call it, you can modify the option of it anytime

Comment: But I don't have a name to call it from... I edited my question to show how it is opened

Comment: Then you will have to declare a public varialbe: `var iframe = ...` outside a function (can be access global) or assign in window object: `window.myiframe = ` then inside iframe, you can call window.parent.myiframe or window.top.myiframe ...